# xcart number_conv.php got virus?

Tags: x-cart

Anyone using xcart ? my hosting provider detected the xcart file include/number_conv.php effected with malicious or virus.

I tried to google it but couldn't find the solution.
Any one know abt this ?

I wanted to post question on xcart but they tends to charge me for answering my question.Also my subscription had expired on xcart.

Answer (score 0):

With my version of xcart, there is no file called that way. Make sure you have the latest. I can assure you that all files of xcart are no danger and not detected by any popular antivirus. I suggest you re-download a good, up-to-date and clean version of the software on the official site **www.x-cart.com**.